# Spring-boot How to show logs on screen?

Tags: spring-boot

I have a method in which I receive a variable `year`, how can I show in the console the value that is stored in said variable?

This is the method I have, I have put a `sysout` but I can't see it.

```
public EmployeeDashboardDto getEmployeeDashboardYearDto(Integer year, Integer employeeId) throws QOException {
        
        System.out.println("year: " + year);        
        
        return null;        
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use debug mode to see if the program enters this method

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63PwG.png)